Python function to fetch matching and error records
I have a json file of the following format:
[
    {
        "type": "BEGIN",
        "id": "XYZ123"
    },
    {
        "type": "END",
        "id": "XYZ123",
    },
    {
        "type": "BEGIN",
        "id": "XYZ456"
    },
    {
        "type": "END",
        "id": "XYZ987"
    },
    {
        "type": "END",
        "id": "XYZ456"
    },
    {
        "type": "BEGIN",
        "id": "XYZ789"
    },
    {
        "type": "",
        "id": "XYZ345"
    }

]

I need to output 2 files:
valid_records.lst:
    "id": "XYZ123"
    "id": "XYZ456"

error_records.lst:
    "id": "XYZ987"
    "id": "XYZ789"
    "id": "XYZ345"

ie., blocks with type both BEGIN and END are valid. Blocks with type either BEGIN or END or none are errors.
This is the code snippet I tried so far:    `
valid_records=[]    
error_records=[]
        for rec in records:
            if rec.get("type") == "BEGIN":
                for rec1 in records:

                    if rec['id'] == rec1['id'] and rec1.get("type") == "END":
                        valid_records.append(rec1)
                         print("valid id : ", rec1['id'])

                    elif rec['id'] == rec1['id'] and rec1.get("type") != "END":
                        print("ignore, duplicate")
                    else:
                        error_records.append(rec1)
                        print("error id : ", rec1['id'])


This prints the valid ids (the ones that have both BEGIN and END) correctly. But when error records are generated it also includes the ids identified earlier as valid. Also, I am not sure how to code it to capture those ids that have just BEGIN, END or none.

I think the reason your code is breaking at the moment is because you're needlessly nesting your loops - you can achieve your intended behaviour by starting with remapping your initial JSON, pairing IDs with lists of the types associated with them. You can do this with defaultdict as I've shown below.
Then, you can check which IDs have both BEGIN and END types, and segregate into two lists accordingly, as below.
EDITED to show how to read in a saved JSON and work upon that.
You start with your JSON file.
[
  { "type": "BEGIN", "id": "XYZ123" },
  { "type": "END", "id": "XYZ123" },
  { "type": "BEGIN", "id": "XYZ456" },
  { "type": "END", "id": "XYZ987" },
  { "type": "END", "id": "XYZ456" },
  { "type": "BEGIN", "id": "XYZ789" },
  { "type": "", "id": "XYZ345" }
]

The script then begins by reading in said JSON file.
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict, List
from json import loads

# Start by reading in the JSON file called "records.JSON" and saved in the same
# working directory as your script. Assign the contents of the JSON to a
# variable called 'all_records' - a list of dictionaries.

with open("records.json", "r") as f:
    all_records: List[Dict] = loads(f.read())

# Create a defaultdict that creates a list for each new (previously unencountered)
# key. 

records_by_id = defaultdict(list) 
valid_records = [] # Emtpy list to hold your valid records
invalid_records = [] # Empty list to hold your invalid records. 

# Loop through each record. Access the "id" key in 'records_by_id'. If the 
# key isn't already in 'records_by_id', being a defaultdict, it will create a
# new key and assign an empty list as its value. Append to that list the "type" 
# of the current 'record'.

for record in all_records:
    records_by_id[record.get("id")].append(record.get("type"))
    
# Iterate through each record_id and the list of types associated with it. 

for record_id, types in records_by_id.items():
    # If the current record_id has a list of types with both "BEGIN" and "END" 
    # in it, the record is deemed valid, and its id is appended to the list of 
    # "valid" records. 
    if "BEGIN" in types and "END" in types:
        valid_records.append(record_id)
        
    # Else, append the current record_id to the list of "invalid" records.
    else:
        invalid_records.append(record_id)

# Checking results:

print(valid_records, sep="\n")
# ['XYZ123', 'XYZ456']

print(invalid_records, sep="\n")
# ['XYZ987', 'XYZ789', 'XYZ345']


Thanks, but wouldn't this mean hard coding the file contents? I need to pass json file as a parameter.

I need the output of json.loads(json_data) to be read by all_records. How to do that?

Sorry for the late response. When you read in a JSON file, it basically assumes the character and appearance of a nested dictionary. In representing your inputs as a dictionary, I did not mean to imply that you would have to hard code it. I was implying (hence the comment up front that the dictionary is a "stand-in" for your initial JSON) that you will have read your JSON file and expressed it as a dictionary, upon which you would then perform the subsequent operations. I will update my answer to clarify this.

I have edited my answer to show how you read in the JSON.
